# QGIS combining categorized values

Tags: qgis, symbology, qgis-2.18

I want to combine categorized symbol data for the sake of symbology. For example: Let's say I classified a data column of a shapefile and it gave me 20 different values. Ten commercial building types and ten residential building types. In Arcgis I could very easily combine that to two symbols, one for residential and one for commercial.

Running QGIS 2.18, MacOS Sierra 10.12.2

Answer (score 2):

The way to go is to use Rule-based symbology (as stated at the end of previous answer)

You may have to adjust the setting to fit your needs, the expression in the picture assume that you use numerical value for classification and you will need to create another rule for residential building.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Ruled-based symbology in QGIS 3.X you can select all the categories you want to group in the Layer Properties-Symbology-Menu and then right click and select "Merge Categories".

Answer (score 1):

You may combine your categorized values from the layer properties.

Firstly, right click on the name of your layer in the **Layers Panel** and then go to `Properties`.

If your categories are stored in a field, go to `Style` and follow the sequence in the image below:

[image]

You can change symbols, colors and other rendering options from the same dialog.

If you want to set specific rules to your rendering, choose the `Rule-based` option instead of `Categorized` from the `Style` dialog.