# Is it possible to draw an attribute to a segment?

Tags: qgis

I have a project that consists of creating a route in order to help cyclists know which route is best.
The objective is to create a route manually that tells the rider the safety zones (by color), the type of route (by the type of line), the inclination (symbolism arrow) and the parallel paths (color of the margin). 
How do I associate a segment with an attribute, for example the security attribute (x = security). Assign a scale of 1 to 5 and whenever the value is 1 it changes the color to red and whenever it is 5 it changes to green.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224448/qgis-combining-categorized-values) and [this](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html)

Comment: Also [this](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_attributes.html)

Comment: You may want to reword you question.  Are you asking how to create the symbols you need to represent your routes or are you asking how to create attributes for your routes?  Or both?

Comment: Each route segment will need to be a separate feature.